# How to use a context variable when passing to a template tag

Tags: django, django-templates

I use the following template tag to allow custom variables to be set inside a template:

```
class SetVarNode(template.Node):
     def __init__(self, new_val, var_name):
        self.new_val = new_val
        self.var_name = var_name

    def render(self, context):
        context[self.var_name] = self.new_val
        return ''

@register.tag
def setvar(parser, token):    
    # This version uses a regular expression to parse tag contents.
    try:
        # Splitting by None == splitting by spaces.
        tag_name, arg = token.contents.split(None, 1)
    except ValueError:
        raise template.TemplateSyntaxError(
            "%r tag requires arguments" % token.contents.split()[0]
        )
    m = re.search(r'(.*?) as (\w+)', arg)
    if not m:
        raise template.TemplateSyntaxError(
            "%r tag had invalid arguments" % tag_name
        )
    new_val, var_name = m.groups()
    if not (new_val[0] == new_val[-1] and new_val[0] in ('"', "'")):
        raise template.TemplateSyntaxError(
            "%r tag's argument should be in quotes" % tag_name
        )
    return SetVarNode(new_val[1:-1], var_name)
```

This lets me set a variable once for use in the template: `{% setvar "a string" as new_template_var %}`

How can I modify this to allow my variable to concatenate with an existing context variable?

E.g. I want to pass `context['var1']` to the setvar as

```
{% setvar "a string {{ var1 }}" as new_template_var %}
```

however the `{{ var1 }}` is included as a string and not the variable value itself.

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution: concat your litteral string and your variable with a filter, ie:

```
{% setvar "a string"|add:var1 as new_template_var %}
```

but you have to [correctly handle templates `Variable`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/custom-template-tags/#passing-template-variables-to-the-tag) and `FilterExpression` in your node to resolve the variable name to it's current context value.

This being said, this is really unecessary (unless you have more requirements or are just doing it for learning purposes):

> Finally, if you only need to have a simple syntax for your custom context-updating template tag, consider using the simple_tag() shortcut, which supports assigning the tag results to a template variable.

(https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/custom-template-tags/#setting-a-variable-in-the-context)

Answer (score -1):

In your `SetVarNode.render(..)`, you'll have to initiate it as a template, and render it with `context`.

Untested:

```
class SetVarNode(template.Node):
    def __init__(self, new_val, var_name):
        self.new_val = new_val
        self.var_name = var_name

    def render(self, context):
        t = Template(self.new_val)
        value = t.render(context)
        context[self.var_name] = value
        return ''
```

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately that results in `'module' object is not callable`

Comment: The proper solution is to use template filters in the templetag call.